# the [] operator in matrices R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

So I know that if you have:

```
m = matrix(1:9, 3,3)
z = as.matrix(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3))
```

and you do

```
m[z] 
# you get back 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

But if you do

```
m[] = m[z]
# You get back a matrix..
```

I'm a little confused as to what this `[]` operator does? why doesnt something like `m[][z]` or `m[z][]` return a matrix? and how would I get it to return a matrix **without** assigning it to a variable `m[]`

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to get back from `m[z]`?  Where is the inconsistency? Remember, in R a `matrix` is just a `vector` with dimensions...

Comment: Well, I expect a matrix. I know that it will return a vector. but instead of creating a new matrix out of the vector like: `matrix(vector, nrow, ncol)`, I found this useful operator. I just couldn't find any documentation on it

Comment: The documentation for "[" can be found with either `?Extract` or `?"["`. It should be studied _carefully_ if you want to avoid other common pitfalls, I would suggest at least 5 complete readings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that when the argument to "[]" (which is really a function) is a two column matrix as you provided, the result will be a vector where the first column specifies the row and the second column specifies the column in operated-upon matrix. This is a "feature" ( and a very handy one I might add)  of the language.

The arguments might or might not contain all of the possible combinations of row and column so the result would not predictably be something that would sensibly be a matrix of the same dimensions. The form: `m[] <- m[ z[1:4, ] ]` will produce a result but also a warning. You should look at the result and then make an effort to understand what is happening.